# Cannot read property 'create' of undefined angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, vendor, typeerror

Angular giving error in the production. Ng build --prod. [error picture below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq6XX.gif)
[My angular cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anEDa.gif)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This is a difficult bug to squash without context because the error is essentially whatever you are trying to access the property 'create' of is undefined.

Comment: quick suggestion: find what object is referencing 'create' and make sure it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

to debug this open your `main.****.bundle.js` and make intent in browser console and try to see where it getting.

in the code you can also guess which function have a create method and debug what it is undefined in --aot build.

Sometime its just the resolver problem, so you can resolve that by adding below dependencies

```
"enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
```

Comment: "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0" is not working. I have created a new project without anything on it  even that is giving me this error